How comes that systemd-resolve becomes owner of the root directory "/ "?
When trying to look at my firewall in Ubuntu 22.04 via:  sudo ufw status
I received the following warning message:
WARN: uid is 0 but '/' is owned by 101
Then I figured out that 101 is nothing else but the process systemd-resolve.
How can this happen ???
Is 101 = systemd-resolve just a coincidence or a part of the problem cause ???
I checked for other irregularities of file or directory ownership, but did not find any others.
Therefore I fixed that via ... carefully using sudo chown root / ... and everything seems to be fine again ... so far.
This problem has left me thinking quite a bit ... I found some similar reports, but almost all described a totally messed up subtree of the filesystem - not just only the root directory - which in most cases had been caused by erreoneous use of the chown command.
Since I do not feel guilty here I am asking whether others have seen similar ghosts ?

Have you verified that / is owned by systemd-resolve? Do ls -la / and look at the top line. Paste the output into your question.

yes, I checked all the ownerships via 'ls -la'  / and 'ls - ld /'   and saw nothing strange in the output ... so I concluded  that just doing 'sudo chown root /'  would not make it worse ... and it became true ... and also ufw did not complain any more with its strange warning. I am not sure whether the problem is gone or whether I have "fixed" only the visible part of the iceberg ???  ... that's why I asked
